# Bevel modifier breaking at large angles

Tags: armature, bevel

I hope someone can help me here. I am a graphic designer and pretty new to Blender. I am trying to mockup a box in blender that I can apply my artwork to. I have imported the dieline in via DXF and added a solidify modifier and a series of bevel modifiers (controlled by vertex groups). I have then added some armatures to the mesh to control the flaps. This is working pretty well until I rotate the flap to 90 degrees, then the bevel breaks. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Upload your blend file here: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @Luciano thanks for that, I have changed out the link in my original post above.